# why browserify build gives error for react build?

Tags: reactjs, browserify, babeljs

i have the following codes , a sample project i done.

**PlayerWrapper.js**

```js
import React from 'react'
import Player from './Player'

class PlayerWrapper extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>before player</h3>
                <Player />
                <h3>after player</h3>
            </div>
        )
    }


}

export default PlayerWrapper
```

**Player.jS**

```js
import React from 'react'

class Player extends React.Component {

    render(){
        return(
            <div><h1>How are you from Player</h1></div>
        )
    }


}

export default Player
```

in the package.json i have the following lines to build the code

```
    "ran": "babel ./as-player/PlayerWrapper.js -o ./as-player/PlayerWrapperwp.js --source-maps --presets react,es2015",
"ranb": "browserify ./as-player/PlayerWrapperwp.js -o ./as-player/PlayerWrapperwp--.js --transform browserify-global-shim --standalone PlayerWrapper"
```

when i build with the babel entry it builds perfectly , but when i use the browserify entry to browserify it get failed giving the following error?

i can't exactly pinpoint an issue with my code, it is a very basic one, can any one suggest what to do or give some pointers to resolve the issue?

react-wrapper-component@0.0.0 ranb E:\DevEnv\nginx-1.8.0\nginx-1.8.0\html\test
browserify ./as-player/PlayerWrapperwp.js -o ./as-player/PlayerWrapperwp--.js --transform browserify-global-shim --standalone PlayerWrapper

SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:7) (while browserify-global-shim was processing E:\DevEnv\nginx-1.8.0\nginx-1.8.0\html\test\as-player\Player.js) while parsing file: E:\DevEnv\nginx-1.8.0\nginx-1.8.0\html\test\as-player\Player.js
    at Parser.pp.raise (E:\DevEnv\nginx-1.8.0\nginx-1.8.0\html\test\node_modules\falafel\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1745:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (E:\DevEnv\nginx-1.8.0\nginx-1.8.0\html\test\node_modules\falafel\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2264:8)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (E:\DevEnv\nginx-1.8.0\nginx-1.8.0\html\test\node_modules\falafel\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2243:59)
    at Parser.pp.parseExpressionStatement (E:\DevEnv\nginx-1.8.0\nginx-1.8.0\html\test\node_modules\falafel\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2677:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseStatement (E:\DevEnv\nginx-1.8.0\nginx-1.8.0\html\test\node_modules\falafel\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2462:160)
    at Parser.pp.parseTopLevel (E:\DevEnv\nginx-1.8.0\nginx-1.8.0\html\test\node_modules\falafel\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:2379:21)
    at parse (E:\DevEnv\nginx-1.8.0\nginx-1.8.0\html\test\node_modules\falafel\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:101:12)
    at module.exports (E:\DevEnv\nginx-1.8.0\nginx-1.8.0\html\test\node_modules\falafel\index.js:22:15)
    at Stream. (E:\DevEnv\nginx-1.8.0\nginx-1.8.0\html\test\node_modules\browserify-transform-tools\lib\transformTools.js:187:21)
    at Stream.end (E:\DevEnv\nginx-1.8.0\nginx-1.8.0\html\test\node_modules\browserify-transform-tools\lib\transformTools.js:108:30)

npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\USAMPR2\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "run" "ranb"
npm ERR! node v4.3.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.4.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! react-wrapper-component@0.0.0 ranb: `browserify ./as-player/PlayerWrapperwp.js -o ./as-player/PlayerWrapperwp--.js --transform browserify-global-shim --standalone PlayerWrapper`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the react-wrapper-component@0.0.0 ranb script 'browserify ./as-player/PlayerWrapperwp.js -o ./as-player/PlayerWrapperwp--.js --transform browserify-global-shim --standalone PlayerWrapper'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the react-wrapper-component package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     browserify ./as-player/PlayerWrapperwp.js -o ./as-player/PlayerWrapperwp--.js --transform browserify-global-shim --standalone PlayerWrapper
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls react-wrapper-component
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     E:\DevEnv\nginx-1.8.0\nginx-1.8.0\html\test\npm-debug.log

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a proper browserify **transform**, like `babelify` or `reactify` configured in your package.json's scripts section. Otherwise, browserify will see es6 code, and throw an error.

Something like

```
browserify ./as-player/PlayerWrapperwp.js -o ./as-player/PlayerWrapperwp--.js -t reactify --transform browserify-global-shim --standalone PlayerWrapper
```